# how to extract youtube thumbnail from youtube link in python

Tags: python, youtube

I want to **extract and display Youtube search results** for a query to the user.

In that process, I have completed fetching the Youtube link and also extracted the title from the link.

Nevertheless I also want the **thumbnail of that link displayed**, same as that displayed in Youtube suggestions section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a question like this, I'd recommend using the [`site:youtube.com`](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=site%3Ayoutube.com) Google Images search, and just have a look at one or two thumbnails. I believe the below should work in all cases, though you'd need to test on different types of videos.

If the video URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxx

The thumbnail URL is https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxxx/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: I tried this but I always get the same image for all the queries and its same as the one in the thumbnail link which you provided

Comment: Thanks I got it.made some typo mistakes in video id.